# Tornado TypeError: _execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'transforms'

Tags: python, tornado

I am using tornado 4.2 with python3.5 and get this exception raised

```
  Future <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x105c58128> exception was never retrieved: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 215, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'transforms'
```

Can someone give me hints what exactly I am missing here ?

Comment: If you don't put the actual code sample is hard to impossible being helped...